# Google Unicode Fonts not rendered properly in mpdf for PHP

Tags: php, pdf, unicode, mpdf, google-fonts

I'm trying to use Baloo2 Google Font in mpdf to render Hindi Language. 
I'm using the Latest Version. 
The PDF is being Rendered but the complex scripts are not being rendered properly.
I'm trying to render the following,

> चातुर्यकला त्रिवेदी 
> But it is rendered as
> चातुर् यकला त् रविदी

Although when inspected in browser, the rendering is proper in inspect source code. but not displayed properly in the PDF.

The Code in my file is

```
$html = ' आवेदक का नाम  : चातुर्यकला त्रिवेदी';
$filename = 'demofile' . time() . '.pdf';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
   'mode' => 'utf-8',
   'default_font' => 'baloo',
]);
   $mpdf->debug = true;
   $mpdf->WriteHTML("p, td {font-family: baloo; color: transparent; white-space: pre; cursor: text; transform-origin: 0% 0%;}", 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output($filename, 'D');
```

I've also copied the fonts in the ttfonts directory and also made changes to the fontVariables.php files as follows

```
'fontdata' => [    
        "baloo" => [
          'R' => "BalooRegular.ttf",
          'useOTL' => 0xFF,
          'useKashida' => 75,
        ]...
    ];
```

When done in this format, an error is thrown

> GPOS Lookup Type 5, Format 3 not supported (ttfontsuni.php)

Pls. let me know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: You should always set up also the language. Fonts need language (and regional) tag to properly display text. I do not know if there are other problems.

Comment: So what tag should I add or code should I add...